# Validating isDisplayed() WebElement attribute in a while loop

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to write a while loop that checks the `isDisplayed()` attribute against a loading element, and prints "it is loading" if the loading window is visible. If the loading window disappears, the while loop will exit.

```
private By superPoseLoading = By.xpath("//span[@class='loading']");

while (true) {

    if (driver.findElement(superPoseLoading).isDisplayed() == true) {
        System.out.println("is loading");

    }else {
        break;
    }
}
```

but even if the if condition is true, the program does not send the message, and the cycle is interrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a slightly different approach than a few of the other answers -- if none of them work for you, feel free to try this out:

```
By loadingIndicator = By.xpath("//span[@class='loading']");
boolean loadingFinished = false;

while (!loadingFinished) 
{
    System.out.println("is loading");

    // attempt to find the loading indicator, catch exception if it is not found
    try {
        WebElement loader = driver.findElement(loadingIndicator);

        // check isDisplayed(), set found to true
        if (!loader.isDisplayed()) loadingFinished = true;

        // handle exception where loadmask no longer exists
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        loadingFinished = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code is checking for the presence of the loadmask, and handles the `NoSuchElementException` that may arise if it does not exist. We set `loadingFinished` to `true` if `loader.isDisplayed()` is false, or if calling `findElement` on the loader returns a `NoSuchElementException`, meaning the element does not exist and the loading has completed.

However, if you want to make this code a lot simpler, you can just use the `ExpectedConditions` class:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

// first, wait for the loadmask to be visible to avoid race condition
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='loading']")));

// now, wait for load mask to disappear -- loading complete after this
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='loading']")));
```

Comment: Your second block is what I would use (except I would use a CSS selector, `span.loading`). One concern I have is that you may run into a race condition where the code looks for the Loading... popup to be visible **before** it's actually present which would cause the wait to be bypassed and then later code fails because the Loading... popup opens and blocks other clicks. I would add a wait for visible __then__ wait for invisible to be sure.

Comment: That makes sense -- I've updated the answer to avoid the race condition. The only 'downside' to using ExpectedConditions is that you can't print 'is loading...' while waiting. But I prefer the ExpectedConditions approach either way, it just depends on what the original asker is trying to accomplish.

Comment: this is very strange, the problem is not in the method or the validation that is used, that span [@ class = 'loading']
try using a Thread.sleep (2000); as a test to wait for the loading window to disappear
and then validate it with an invisibilityOfElementLocated () and throw error ... the problem is of the page, equally, thanks for your help ^^

Comment: I just took `//span[@class='loading']` from the code sample you provided. Since I can't see the HTML on your page, I'm not sure what the actual locator for this should be. Using explicit wait here is really not good practice, especially because you know what element you are waiting on.

Comment: @Christine In your last comment when you state, "Using explicit wait here is really not good practice...", I'm assuming that you were referring to the `Thread.sleep()`? It might be misunderstood that you were talking about `ExpectedConditions`.

Comment: Right, `ExpectedConditions` is a type of explicit wait, so I am referring to `Thread.Sleep()` specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need if statement and don't need to assign true to .isDisplayed() method, because it's always return boolean.

```
 while (driver.findElement(superPoseLoading).isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("is loading");
            }
```

Comment: but when I try a simpler validation, like this:

while (driver.findElement (superPoseLoading) .isDisplayed ()) {

         System.out.println ("is loading");
}
ignore the cycle even when the loading window is present

Comment: Its really interesting, because before I posted it. I checked this code in my tests and its working as expected, keep printing "Its loading" in console, I was using button on the page, so what I'm thinking is, that problem with element u r using, its can't be checked with .isDisplayed() method. Can we get html code for this element or link.

Comment: I begin to believe the same ... this element By superPoseLoading = By.xpath ("// span [@ class = 'loading']");
It cannot be validated with an isDisplayed (), I also tried isEnabled () but it created infinite cycles ...

Answer (score 0):

This approach could have issues with exceptions thrown when the element does not exist for example. I would recomend to use approach like this:

```
By superPoseLoadingLocator = By.xpath("//span[@class='loading']");
List<WebElement> waiter = driver.findElements(superPoseLoadingLocator);
while (!waiter.isEmpty() && waiter.get(0).isDisplayed()){
    System.out.println("Loading...");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   waiter = driver.findElements(superPoseLoadingLocator);
}
// .. do the staff after the loading has been completed
```

I am really sorry for using `Thread.sleep()` here. I'm just showing an idea.